Angular redirectTo: to pass data to redirected route
Is there any way to pass the "data" to home component only when redirected from oldpath, but not from ''?
const routes: Routes = [
      {path : '', redirectTo:'home'},
      {path : 'oldPath', redirectTo:'home', data: {defaultAction: 'oldPath'}},
      {path : 'home', component : homeComponent, resolve:{shapeLoaded:integrationResolver}}
    ];

I don't want to duplicate the home path with another entry.


You can pass "data" to any router using navigate in the "state
property" instead of use the own data in router like this SO

Or you can use a service and store/clear the desired value before
navigate.

Or you can store the "previousPage" like show this link
Simplify, you create a service -in the link use a Subject, but you
can simply use variables-
@Injectable({providedIn:'root')
export class UrlService {
  public previousUrl: string="";
  public currentUrl: string="";
  constructor() { }
}

And in your main.app
  constructor(private router: Router,
              private urlService: UrlService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
      this.urlService.previousUrl=this.urlService.currentURL 
      this.urlService.currentUrl = event.url;
    });
  }



